Error with Linked ARM Template in Data Factory CI/CD: "InvalidTemplate - Deployment template validation failed
While working on a Proof of Concept (POC) for CI/CD in Azure Data Factory, I encountered an error when deploying using a linked ARM template. The deployment succeeds when using a standalone ARM template, but fails with the linked ARM version. The error message is as follows:
ERROR: InvalidTemplate - Deployment template validation failed: 'The template resource '/pipeline1' for type 'Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/pipelines' at line '25' and column '63' has incorrect segment lengths. A nested resource type must have identical number of segments as its resource name. A root resource type must have segment length one greater than its resource name.
my yaml :
     - task: AzureCLI@2
        inputs:
          azureSubscription: 'ADF-DEVOPS-SP'
          scriptType: 'bash'
          scriptLocation: 'inlineScript'
          inlineScript: |
            rg="xxxxxxxxxxxx"
            sa="xxxxxxxxxxx"
            cn="xxxxxxxx"
            az storage container create --name $cn --account-name $sa --public-access off --auth-mode login
            sasToken=$(az storage container generate-sas \
                --account-name $sa \
                --name $cn \
                --permissions lrw \
                --expiry $(date -u -d "1 hour" '+%Y-%m-%dT%H:%MZ') \
                --auth-mode login \
                --as-user)
            if [ -z "$sasToken" ]; then
                echo "Failed to generate SAS token."
                exit 1
            fi
            armTemplateFolderPath="$(Build.Repository.LocalPath)/build/armTemplate/linkedTemplates"
            for filePath in "$armTemplateFolderPath"/*; do
                blobName=$(basename "$filePath")
                az storage blob upload --account-name $sa --container-name $cn --name "$blobName" --file "$filePath" --auth-mode login
                if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
                    echo "Failed to upload file '$blobName' to container '$cn'."
                    exit 1
                fi
            done
            sasToken="?$(echo $sasToken | tr -d '"')"
            echo "SAS Token: $sasToken"
            containerUrl="https://adfcicdpocdev.blob.core.windows.net/arm"
            az deployment group what-if \
                --resource-group $rg \
                --mode Incremental \
                --template-file $(Build.Repository.LocalPath)/build/armTemplate/linkedTemplates/ArmTemplate_master.json \
                --parameters @$(Build.Repository.LocalPath)/build/armTemplate/linkedTemplates/ArmTemplateParameters_master.json \
                --parameters containerUri=$containerUrl containerSasToken=$sasToken factoryName=$adfName


In your ARM template files, when defining the custom name of the ADF pipeline, try to change '/pipeline1 to be 'ADF-name/pipeline1' or 'pipeline1'.

The /pipeline1 reference is automatically generated by the Data Factory ARM template; we haven't made any modifications to it. Additionally, the deployment works without any errors when using a standalone ARM template. However, when switching to the linked ARM template, the error appears.

Have you checked the template deployment schema properly. @ShahidHaider

Is the standalone ARM template has the exactly same JSON content as the linked ARM template? Can you post the JSON contents of the two templates? @ShahidHaider

yes it is this is working

task: AzureResourceManagerTemplateDeployment@3
inputs:
deploymentScope: 'Resource Group'
azureResourceManagerConnection: 'ADF-DEVOPS-SP'
subscriptionId: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
action: 'Create Or Update Resource Group'
resourceGroupName: 'ADF-CICD-DEMO-PROD'
location: 'South India'
templateLocation: 'Linked artifact'


csmFile: '$(Pipeline.Workspace)/dll-adf-poc-dev-armTemplate/ARMTemplateForFactory.json'
csmParametersFile: '$(Pipeline.Workspace)/dll-adf-poc-dev-armTemplate/ARMTemplateParametersForFactory.json'
overrideParameters: '-factoryName $(adfName) -AzureDataLakeStorage1_properties_typeProperties_url $(PROD-SA)'
deploymentMode: 'Incremental'

but this not
az deployment group create 
--resource-group $rg 
--mode Incremental 
--template-file $(Pipeline.Workspace)/dll-adf-poc-dev-armTemplate/ARMTemplateForFactory.json 
--parameters $(Pipeline.Workspace)/dll-adf-poc-dev-armTemplate/ARMTemplateParametersForFactory.json 
--parameters factoryName=$adfName


A nested resource type must have identical number of segments as its resource name.

It means that the resource type should be
parent-resource/sub-resource, and if you are passing just a name of the sub-resource, instead of parent-resource/sub-resource the above error occurs. Below is the correct format of defining the name of the child resource.
"name": "[format('{0}/{1}', parameters('dataFactoryName'), parameters('pipelineName'))]"

or
As mentioned by @Bright Ran-MSFT, you can also define it in the below way.
"name": "[concat(parameters('Datafactory'), '/pipelinename')]"


    {
      "type": "Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/pipelines",
      "apiVersion": "2018-06-01",
      "name": "[format('{0}/{1}', parameters('dataFactoryName'), parameters('pipelineName'))]", or "name": "[concat(parameters('factoryName'), '/pipeline1')]"
      "properties": {
        "activities": [
          {
            "name": "CopyActivity",
            "type": "Copy",
            "typeProperties": {
              "source": {
                "type": "BinarySource",
                "storeSettings": {
                  "type": "AzureBlobStorageReadSettings",
                  "recursive": true
                }
              },
              "sink": {
                "type": "BinarySink",
                "storeSettings": {
                  "type": "AzureBlobStorageWriteSettings"
                }
              },
              "enableStaging": false
            },
            "inputs": [
              {
                "referenceName": "xxxx",
                "type": "DatasetReference"
              }
            ],
            "outputs": [
              {
                "referenceName": "xxxxx",
                "type": "DatasetReference"
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    }


Refer MSDoc for the detailed schema structure for deploying an Azure data factory pipelines template.
And if you are facing an error specifically with the Linked template artifact, check your template has a properly defined architecture as shown below.
Sample Linked template:
   {
            "type": "Microsoft.Resources/deployments",
            "apiVersion": "2020-06-01",
            "name": "monitoring",
            "properties": {
              "mode": "Incremental",
                "templateLink": {
                  "relativePath": "deploy.json"
                },
                "parameters": {
                  "location": {
                      "value": "[parameters('location')]"
                  }
                }
            }
    }

Refer SO worked by me for using the linked template schema in a different ways.
If still the issue persists with the linked template, use
az deployment validate for template validation and find out the issue easily.

Have you tried the above approach. @Shahid Haider
